# Could not attach to pid : “557”

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, imessage-extension

I am currently building an iMessage extension app and whenever I try to build and run the app on a device I get an error.

```
Could not attach to pid : “557”
Domain: IDEDebugSessionErrorDomain
Code: 3
Failure Reason: Error 1
```

The app builds fine for the simulator; however, it doesn’t work on devices. I have tried multiple devices including an iPhone 6+ running iOS 12.4.6 and an iPhone X running iOS 13.4.1.

I have already done `sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable` in the terminal for the Mac. Is there anything that must be done to set up the device itself?

If anyone could help me get the app running on a device that would be great because you can't have an app that doesn't work on the device itself.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Quit Xcode, clean build, clear derived data and run again, this works usually for me.

Comment: After cleaning and clearing the derived data I just got a new error: Could not attach to pid : “603”

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake in that the developer had to be trusted on the device. If you have this problem go to the following on the device:

Settings > General > Device Management

Tap on the profile for the developer of the app you are testing and click trust.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem when i was build mac app, and my solution is as follows, set the Xcode settings:

```
TARGETS -> Build Settings -> Signing
```

set `Code signing inject base entitlements` as `Yes`